# Plotting NYC points in R

Tags: r, geolocation, gis

I have around 55 centroids (at the center of each NYC PUMA area as per american community survey) that I want to do geographically weighted regression on.

I have:

```
X   Y   pumace10    events_2008 events_2009
-73.9092456917  40.8916125162   3701    2   0
-73.8617096298  40.8899373255   3702    0   0
-73.8010284966  40.8460832277   3703    1   1
```

and so on...

I want to plot this in R but every time I do:

```
plot(nnyc_data, pch=16, col='firebrick',add=TRUE)
```

(as per this tutorial https://rpubs.com/chrisbrunsdon/101305 )

I get

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

And this is despite looking at other answers on stackoverflow that suggest clearing all plots and adjusting margins/plot window... I've tried all different sizes etc.

Does anyone know how I can plot these points successfully?

Thanks!

N.B.

This doesn't help, I still get the same error:

```
> par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
> plot(nnyc_data, pch=16, col='firebrick',add=TRUE)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Comment: in the end it looks like the margin of your plot is too large and it doesn't fits inside the space allocated for the plot! before you set your margin to 1,1,1,1 as listed below try to run `dev.off()` first to reset your graphics device and try again. May be it helps

Comment: Nope, afraid not... same error... arg!